# What is the danger in including the same JavaScript library twice?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

One of the webapps I'm working in is made up of many partial HTML files. If the partial requires a JavaScript library such as YUI, the YUI library is included in the partial.

When the partials are combined at runtime, the resulting HTML often includes the YUI library several times.

```
<html>
... 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/yahoo/yahoo-min.js"></script>
... 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/yahoo/yahoo-min.js"></script>
... 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/yahoo/yahoo-min.js"></script>
...
</html>
```

I've seen strange behavior from including jQuery several times, especially when using AJAX. Why, specifically, is including the same JavaScript library more than once a bad idea? Why does it only sometimes cause problems?

Comment: The biggest risk is that it would cause the browser to form a singularity in the client machine that eventually grows into a black hole that swallows the entire planet... so please don't do it. ;)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner If you put that as an answer, I'll up vote you. Twice.

Comment: If he puts that as an answer, I will up-vote him 42 times.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Depending on the library, including it more than once could have undesired effects.

Think of it like this, if you have a script that binds a click event to a button, and you include that script twice, those actions will be ran twice when the button is clicked.

You could write a simple function that you call to load a script and have it keep track of files that have already been loaded. Or, I'm sure you could probably use a pre-existing JS loader such as LabJS and modify it.

Comment: It's all about *re-entrancy*. Just now it's in terms of a "module load" and not function execution. Did the designers do something (silly) that would make a second inclusion *break* the logic? Normally this should not be the case but it's possible to imagine scenarios where it is true -- particularly where each run-through is dependent upon some external state and the logic is incorrectly applied.

Answer (score 11):

You should take an approach I learned examining the source of [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/):

```
<script>
    !window.YAHOO && document.write(
        unescape('%3Cscript src="/js/yahoo/yahoo-min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E')
    );
</script>
```

I don't use YUI, so replace `!window.YAHOO` with whatever global YUI uses.

This approach will only load the library if it does not yet exist in the global scope.

Comment: There are ways to do this without resorting to `document.write`, which has all sorts of issues. HTML5 Boilerplate doesn't use this piece of code any more.

Answer (score 9):

The browser will cache the file, downloading it only once. It will be executed more than once however. So the performance impact is negligible, but the correctness impact might not be.

Comment: It will evaluate it more than once, though.

Comment: In a negligible heartbeat, though.

Comment: úlio, that comment doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Not necessarily.  It might have to rebuild all the objects, and lead to a lot of garbage collection.  That can take quite a few tens of milliseconds -- causing a noticeable lag in the page load.

Comment: úlio The evaluation may not be expensive (in terms of time, or in this case, heartbeats) but may cause your code to not work as expected. As an example... loading jQuery, and then jQuery UI, and then some custom jQuery UI widgets. Then load jQuery UI again and whoops! Your custom widgets aren't there any more!

Comment: Loading a library can have serious side effects, but depends on how it is written. For example. overwriting objects/data in global scope. But the script could check if its own global name already exists and not execute again.

Answer (score 7):

It gets **executed each time**. Dependending on the file, this may be undesirable. For instance, if the file contains `alert("hello")`, it will display the alert box for every time the file is referenced, and you may have intended for it to be only displayed once.

### Writing safe libraries:

Here's how you work around it if you only want a one-time execution. Let's say you're writing a library `foobar.js`, which exports one global, `foobar`:

```
function foobar() {
 // ...
}
```

You could make sure that any repeat executions of the file become no-ops, using code like this:

```
window.foobar = window.foobar || function foobar() {
  // ...
};
```

A more modern approach would be to use [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#Applying_the_module_to_your_HTML) instead. JavaScript modules are only ever executed at most once:

```
<script type="module" src="example.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="example.js"></script>
<!-- example.js will only be executed once -->
```

### Using unsafe libraries:

If you can't modify the source code of the library, and you've determined it's unsafe, here's one way to work around it to load the library only once. Create a global and use it each time to check if the script has already been loaded. You'll have to set the global to true yourself.

```
<script>(function() {
  if (! window.foobar) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true; // remove this if you don't want the script to be async
    script.src = 'foobar.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    window.foobar = true;
 }
}();</script>
```